# Find the difference between two date fields that are within a certain time parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have tried this a few ways but here is my pseudo-code for SQL:

```
select count(*) as counter 
where startDate and endDate is 30 minutes and archived = 1.
```

The datatypes for mssql fields are `datetime`

The other idea I had was to bring it up to the `select` statement and add a `dateadd` to the `datdiff` but I was not sure how to account for the two seperate fields (`startDate`,`EndDate`)...

I hope someone can straighten me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartDate,EndDate) <= 30
AND Archived = 1
```

Comment: +1, though `DATEDIFF(minute)` would be the same for `00:59` with `01:01` (2 seconds apart) and `00:01` with `01:59` (118 seconds apart).

Comment: Depending on the precision required, you're better off with something like `...where convert(double,datediff(ms,StartDate,EndDate))/1000.0 <= 30.000`. That will give you ~ 3ms precision (the resolution of the SQL Server datetime value). Beware of ginormous timespans, though. `datediff()` returns a 32-bit int: it can hold at most ~ 24.8 days' worth of milliseconds. Exceed that and you'll get an overlow error.

Comment: @Nicholas: why comparing `DATEDIFF` when you can compare dates themselves? `DATEDIFF` can be a right solution if `30` minutes apart means "having 30 exact minutes in between" in @op's model, but if the @op really means `1800` seconds, then you should compare dates.

Comment: Because it more closely expresses the stated intent of the OP's problem statement. Not to say that your solution is incorrect or somehow worse. In fact, yours is actually better as it doesn't have to deal with the possibility of overflow. Just improving this particular answer, as it doesn't take into account the somewhat curious internal operation of `datediff()` (e.g., there is a 1 year difference between '2010-12-31 23:59:59.996' and '2011-01-01 00:00:00.000' despite the fact that the two are a mere 4ms apart. That's some sort of rounding!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   endDate <= DATEADD(minute, 30, startDate)
        AND archieved = 1
```